# Multiplexing data over socket

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, protocols, multiplexing

Basically I'm trying to have 2 - 3 file transfers from the same socket **BUT** all of them at the same time and yet not to interrupt messages sent back and to client/server.

Similar to a chat program between 2 people and 3 file transfers occurring.

I'm trying to avoid opening up 2 or more streams.

I want everything to occur asynchronously - still talk and transfer all 3 files at the **same time** ; not one after another.

How would my protocol look like? I can't think of this.

Comment: Many client-server systems that allow multiple chats and/or multiple file transfers use separate connections for each chat/transfer. It's _much_ easier that way than to packet-switch the connection yourself.

Comment: Yes I'm well aware of that, but I'm asking specifically for packet switching myself. Got any idea how I can go about it?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do the packet switching yourself, I recommend a queue: Put packets that needs to be sent in one end, and in the other end you take packets and do the actual wire transfer.

For the packets that go over the wire, you need a type (file transfer or chat), a destination (where to put the file, or who you're chatting with), and the actual packet data.

On the receiving side you need to keep track of all recipients, chat and file transfers. When receiving a file transfer for destination X you save it to file X, if you receive a chat message for person Y you send the message on to person Y.

Comment: But how would you determine which packet is for which file? you would have then to keep sending the file path in every chunk which causes big overhead.

Comment: @amaninlove Now this is some time ago, so some details are a little foggy, but I think I meant multiplexing the different *types* of messages. Meaning you can only have one file-transfer active at a time, but the packages for it could be multiplexed with other types of packages (for example char messages).

Comment: i get it what you mean. By that approach, does it effect the download speed? for example, which is faster multiple files are being multiplexed over a single socket or a distinct socket per file?

Comment: @amaninlove You still need to multiplex. Either over multiple files on the single socket, or over the multiple sockets for each file. Multiple socket solution  could scale better (to a limit of course) considering that it allows each socket to be handled by a separate thread or process. You might still get a choking point if all sockets are for files on the same old-style spinning platter hard-drive (less of a problem for an SSD).

Comment: What i meant is if you only have 1 outstanding **recv** on a socket at a given time then the single socket for multiple files could be slow. The problem with a distinct socket per file is this new socket has no relationship with other sockets so how would you know that this file's socket belongs to this user? (different user's socket say the chat socket for instance and it resides in a different memory address). I found no way to solve this unless the chat's socket memory address is sent to the client and then client keeps sending it back with the file's chunks. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: @amaninlove You need some kind of structure in a container to keep track of all connections. And if you're just using a single thread in a single process, then multiplexing over a single socket is probably going to be more efficient.

Comment: My server is multi-threaded. However, it is only using one outstanding async **WSARecv** at a time on a given socket. When this call finishes, i will post another outstanding receive and so on. So it is to avoid out of order receives due to thread scheduling and context switches. Thanks for the advice. I will consider this solution of yours.